# Formula to add a dash it only if there’s no numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I have a list of items in column A that can begin with numbers or letter ants and may either have special characters or not. I want to add a dash after the first three letters but exclude a cell that begins with numbers or may already have any special characters. How can I do this?

Examples
Column A.

1. 123456
2. 123abc
3. ABC123
4. ABC-123
5. A-123Bc

From the above the only cell that should return a response in column B would be line 3 because that is the only line that does not have numbers as the first three characters and also has no dashes

Is there a way to write a formula that will do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following formula in B1:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VALUE(LEFT(A1,3))>=0,""),IF(IFERROR(FIND("-",A1),0)>0,"", REPLACE(A1,4,0,"-")))
```

Drag it down to fill the other cells.

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly

Comment: @Halo You can mark the answer as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)